# How can I send Image attachment in custom email from controller in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: custom, email-templates, image-upload, magento2.3.2, attachment

I have created custom module for quotation in Magento2.3.0.

Module is working as per requirement but I want to send an attachment also in the email which is not working.

I am sending email from controller. can anyone suggest how can I send the attachment in the email?

My controller code is:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomForm\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $_escaper;

    protected $_filesystem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
    ) {
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        $this->_filesystem = $fileSystem;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storeManager=$objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        $baseMediaUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
                    ->getStore()
                    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $scopeConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');

        $emailAdmin = $scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_custom1/email', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE );
        $nameAdmin = $scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_custom1/name', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE );

        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $model = $objectManager->create('Vendor\CustomForm\Model\Customform');
        $imagePath = '';

        if(1)
        {
            $result = '';

            $profileImage = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('image');
            $fileName = ($profileImage && array_key_exists('name', $profileImage)) ? $profileImage['name'] : null;
            if ($profileImage && $fileName) {
                try {
                    /** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $uploader */
                    $uploader = $objectManager->create(
                        'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                        ['fileId' => 'image']
                    );
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapterFactory */
                    $imageAdapterFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')
                        ->create();
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                    $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
                    $mediaDirectory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

                    $result = $uploader->save(
                        $mediaDirectory
                            ->getAbsolutePath('customform_customform')
                    );

                    $imagePath = $result['file'];
                    $model->setFile('customform_customform'.$result['file']); //Database field name
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    if ($e->getCode() == 0) {
                        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            $model->setData('name', $post['fullName']);
            $model->setData('email', $post['email']);
            $model->setData('phone', $post['phone']);
            $model->setData('metal_type', $post['metal_type']);
            $model->setData('ring_size', $post['ring_size']);
            $model->setData('budget', $post['budget']);
            $model->setData('links_to_design', $post['links_to_design']);
            $model->setData('comments', $post['comments']);
            $model->save();

$uploadedFile =  $baseUrl.'pub/media/customform_customform'.$imagePath;


$this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

            $sender = [
                'name' => $nameAdmin,
                'email' => $emailAdmin
            ];

            $sentToEmail = $post['email'];

            $sentToName = $post['fullName'];


            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('customemail_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => 'frontend',
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars([
                    'name'  => $post['fullName'],
                    'email'  => $post['email'],
                    'phone' => $post['phone'],
                    'metalType' => $post['metal_type'],
                    'ringSize' => $post['ring_size'],
                    'budget' => $post['budget'],
                    'links' => $post['links_to_design'],
                    'uploadedImage' => $uploadedFile,
                    'comments' => $post['comments']
                ])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($sentToEmail,$sentToName)
                //->attachFile($uploadedFileName, $uploadedFile)
                //->addTo('owner@example.com','owner')
                ->getTransport();

                $transport->sendMessage();

               $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('Something missing in your details!')
            );
        }
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension which allows you to attach a file to the contact form

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactAttachment

Take a look at the controller. It has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to attach the file in mail, Please follow the below steps

**Step #1: Need to extend the core transportbuilder**

**File path: root/app/Faceless/AttachmentModule/etc/di.xml;**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="\Faceless\AttachmentModule\Magento\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

---

**Step #2: Introduce the attachment file type in addAttachment() method**

**File path: root/app/Faceless/AttachmentModule/Magento/Mail/Template;**

```
<?php

namespace Faceless\AttachmentModule\Magento\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    public function addAttachment($fileName,$attachedName)
    {
        $this->message->createAttachment(
            $fileName,
            'text/csv',
            \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
            $attachedName
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE**: Here i was used CSV file, you can change the format

**Step #3: Inject the class and prepare attachment file with data**

```
private $transportBuilder;
private $csvWriter;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
\Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvWriter
) {
    $this->csvWriter    = $csvWriter;
    $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
}

public function prepareCsv($data)
    { 
    // $filePath = '/var/www/html/magentoRoot 
    // you can get the path from  \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR;
    $data[0] = ['SKU', 'Store', 'Price', 'SpecialPrice', 'Status']; // header for the csv file
    $data[1] = ['prod-1', 'Primary Store', '1000', '500', 'Enabled']; // You can use proper push function for more data
        $this->csvWriter
            ->setEnclosure('"')
            ->setDelimiter(',')
            ->saveData($filePath ,$data);
        return $filePath;
    }
```

---

**Step #4: Use the below logic where you required - addAttachment(content, filename)**

```
$transport  = $this->transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('mail_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions( [
                    'area' => 'frontend',
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
            ])
                    ->setTemplateVars([
                    'name'  => $post['fullName'],
                    'email'  => $post['email'],
                    'phone' => $post['phone'],
                    'metalType' => $post['metal_type'],
                    'ringSize' => $post['ring_size'],
                    'budget' => $post['budget'],
                    'links' => $post['links_to_design'],
                    'uploadedImage' => $uploadedFile,
                    'comments' => $post['comments']
             ])
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo('faceless@gmail.com');
                ->addAttachment(file_get_contents($file), 'facelessFilename.csv') : ''; // facelessFilename.csv - attachment name in mail
$transport->getTransport()->sendMessage();
```

**Hope this help you, Please follow this and let me know. Happy to contribute.**

Comment: can you share complete proper code of this extension ?