# Magento 2 : addAttachment is not working

Tags: magento2, email-translation, attachment

I was lots of tries to send the attachment to mail but no luck. Please check my below code and please correct me where I am wrong.

```
<?php
/**
 * KiwiCommerce
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade to newer versions in the future.
 * If you wish to customize this module for your needs.
 * Please contact us https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/contacts.
 *
 * @category   KiwiCommerce
 * @package    KiwiCommerce_AdminActivity
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2018 Kiwi Commerce Ltd (https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/)
 * @license    https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/magento2-extension-license/
 */
namespace KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

/**
 * Class ClearLog
 * @package KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Cron
 */
class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $_request;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $filePath = 'C:/new/xampp/htdocs/Uplifting-Products/var/export/Adminactivity/admin_activity_09_11_2019_14_35_49.csv';

        $fileName = 'admin_activity_09_11_2019_14_35_49.csv';

        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('modulename_test_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
            ->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
                ]
            )
            ->setFrom('general')
            // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
            ->addTo('gagaugaugaug@gmail.com', 'Customer Name')
            ->addAttachment($filePath,$fileName)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Also i have completed the below process after run above code.

To add an attachment programmatically in the email, first, you need to override **\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder** class.

> Step 1: app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="\[Namespace]\[Module]\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
Step 2: app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

<?php

namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder {

    public function addAttachment(
    $filePath, $filename = null, $mimeType = \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM, $disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $encoding = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64
    ) {
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            $body = file_get_contents($filePath);
            $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Now, you can call addAttachment() function while sending an email.

Note: addAttachment function requires 2 parameters: filePath and fileName.

Comment: which version of magento 2 you are using?

Comment: @Avesh Naik Magento ver. 2.3.2

Comment: The above approch doesn't work in 2.3 Check This https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254895/how-to-add-attachment-with-email-magento-2-3?rq=1

Comment: **Hope this help you** https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/288226/how-can-i-send-image-attachment-in-custom-email-from-controller-in-magento-2-3-0/288241#288241

Answer (score 0):

for magento 2.2.8, 2.2.9, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2 versions you can check this solution

> https://github.com/extait-com/email-attachment

for email attachment

Comment: but how can i use in my module.

Comment: in above solution you can add code to your custom module just copy code.
if file exist then simply add code if file not created then create file in path.

Comment: It's give me error like below 

[2019-09-12 09:44:35] main.CRITICAL: Error when running a cron job {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Error when running a cron job at C:\
ew\\xampp\\htdocs\\Uplifting-Products\\vendor\\magento\\module-cron\\Observer\\ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:327, Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method KiwiCommerce\\EnhancedSMTP\\Email\\Log\\SaveEmailLog\\Interceptor::addAttachment() at C:\
ew\\xampp\\htdocs\\Uplifting-Products\\app\\code\\KiwiCommerce\\AdminActivity\\Cron\\Test.php:64)"} []

Comment: can you refer this may be it's helps you
https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-email-attachments/issues/4

Comment: @ chandresh chauhan i am not using mageplaza module.